# Trying to automate uploading excel file to webpage with VBA, but webpage source just has a few .js confusing

Tags: javascript, vba, file, automation, upload

I was reviewing some automation tutorials on opening web pages. So I used VBA to open a webpage, and it worked. I have a work webpage, where I need to click a drop-down menu, and select import excel, then browse to the excel file and it imports the data, then I have to click save button on webpage to save the import.

I opened the work page source, and all there is , is different .js things, nothing about drop-down menus or nothing that says import excel or save button. Is there still a way to automate and access that drop down menu and import my excel file? None of the tutorials I read so far really talked about interacting with buttons and .js path.

Comment: Right-click on the part of the page you want to interact with, and select "Inspect".  That should open your browser's developer tools and show the HTML behind the object.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to know!